# Task and resource management for non-projects

Tags: project-management, planning

I am looking for a tool for managing tasks assigned to my team; there are lots of options for this such as Asana, but I also want to manage my team members as resources. There are some tools for resource management such as Gantt. But neither task management tools nor resource management tools help me correctly.

Our tasks are not easily splitted to projects so I am not looking for very detailed project management tool like MS Project. I just want to create task and track their history such as

- Schedule task estimated start and finish dates like, dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm
- Actual start and finish dates
- To who this task assigned
- If task rescheduled, who rescheduled, when and why?
- Also I need description and comments on tasks
- Tasks may be dependent to others
- Estimated and actual time logs

As resource management, I want to

- See my resources timesheets according to assigned tasks to them
- See who is overloaded, or free?
- Change their plans easily by drag & drop tasks on their timesheet
- They should see their daily or weekly plan from time sheet

Firstly I think this is not very complicated requirement and I could find lots of tools but I can only find, task management tools or resource management tools or very complicated project management tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have read your all requirements and want to recommend perfect solution for it. [Proofhub.com](http://www.proofhub.com) matched with your all requirements mentioned above. I would say it as an Pro project management tool detailed seems to be boring :P

**Features:**

- Timesheet
- Group Chat
- Gantt Charts
- Discussions
- Task Management
- Set Custom roles
- Mark User as Private

Comment: thank you very much, it is really match with my requirements; only there isn't any task history but may be they can add.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you are still looking but I found this reasonably priced product called [AccountSight](https://www.accountsight.com/).

It provides the following features:

1. A precise time tracking tool with a stopwatch feature, to mark exact start and end times for tasks.
2. Resource allocation tool, where you can easily check your available resources, assign your resources tasks, confirm their allocated time, even define the percentage of time they should work on a task.
3. Scheduling tool lets you maintain schedules for your team members and employees.
4. The reporting segment gives you a detailed overview of what is happening at present in your company. It gives you data on present scenario, resources and their availability, budget, tasks, etc.
5. Can give you forecasted time vs. actual time on projects, tasks, etc.
6. AccountSight can be integrated with Quickbooks and Paypal.

Comment: Do you have any affiliation with AccountSight?

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your comment. I have talked with their customer service and used the software as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you are still looking, [Eylean Board](http://www.eylean.com) seems to fit most of the requirements written here. It works a little bit differently when it comes to the resource timesheets, but you can get the exact same information. So if you are not completely fixed on the idea of getting the info that way - you might like it. My team especially enjoys the ease of use it provides.