# Resource management for event planning

Tags: planning, resource-management

Unlike [Resource scheduling](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/27146/226), I have rooms/venues, to which I want to assign events, i.e.:

- Room 2 has Activity C tomorrow at 8am
- Room 5 has Activity X next week all day
- etc.

I want to be able to have the agenda of a room, or all activities for X day. That I can add/view information in my mobile, it could be a self hosted web based solution or an application.

The deficiencies of calendar-like applications, is that I can't organize events by arbitrary variables, like coordinator or location of the event.

Answer (score 1):

(This is not the full answer, but at least gives you options for well suitable frontend components. You'd have to add the backend yourself.)

### FullCalendar + Scheduler

You could use [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) together with the [Scheduler](https://fullcalendar.io/scheduler) add-on.

FullCalendar is an open source, interactive JavaScript calendar component. It is used in quite a lot of calendaring / resource booking applications. A major rework "version 4" is just out (in an alpha release, as of 2018-12).

What's really great for the context here is the Scheduler add-on, which allows you to list bookings in a grid:

- The grid columns are the time axis, and can be minutes, hours or also days (!, as demonstrated in the [custom scale demo](https://fullcalendar.io/releases/fullcalendar-scheduler/1.9.4/demos/scale.html)).
- The grid rows are the axis for your arbitrary variable which you would let the user switch in the UI (event location, coordinator etc.).

### DHTMLX Scheduler

The only alternative component I know for this is [DHTMLX Scheduler](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/index.html). It comes with several "views", some of which are in the GPL version and some only in the [commercial version](https://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/licenses.shtml).

Unfortunately for your case, the two views that would suit your needs ([Timeline View](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/timeline_view.html) and [Units View](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/units_view.html)) are both only available in the commercial version.